# Sliding force less or equal?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Why is the force required to slide a magnet off a steel plate A LOT less than the force required to directly pull it off?

The force required to pull the magnet can be: 20lb
While the force required to slide the magnet can be: 1lb more/less.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

When you slide a magnet off a plate, you are doing the same amount of work as when you pull it directly off (slightly more, in fact, because of the friction). However, while it's the same amount of work, it's spread out over a much larger distance, and so requires much less force. When you slide a magnet off a plate, the force decreases gradually, starting as soon as the magnet reaches the edge of the plate. When you pull a magnet off a surface perpendicularly, the force is quite large when the magnet is touching it, but decreases quickly as soon as it is a short distance away.

The basic principle is the same as the one that makes levers, double pulley systems, and switchbacks useful. Since work = force × distance, increasing the distance reduces the force required.

Comment: I don't think so... I did some experiments, having to equal sized magnets attracted to each other, the amount of work done sliding them off is much less. In fact, the force is not as strong as a direct pull. You're right, it could be that by increasing the distance you are doing a lot of work, but I doubt it could ever equal the same amount of work pulling it away from a magnet/steel plate. We need to look at the magnetic force being applied. I think it only acts in one direction maybe? By sliding it the magnetic force is not resistive it stays the same only counter force is friction.

Comment: Ignoring friction, pulling a magnet off a plate perpendicularly has to require the same amount of work as pulling it off by sliding it. Otherwise, you could build a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @HYP Peter Shor is using the very specific meaning of "work" that is standard in physics. I think you may be confusing "doing a lot of work" with "applying a large force" which are not the same thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29

Comment: Makes sense. I'll study this some more.

Comment: This has to be wrong--the force required to slide the magnet across the surface is something that doesn't depend on the size of the surface.  Actually getting the magnet off, however, happens only at the edge.  If I double the size of my metal plate, I'll double the "sliding work" without affecting the force.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but if I were to hazard a guess, it would have something to do with the way that the induced magnetic field from the plate falls off as you have the magnet approach the edge of the plate--I hypothesize that it would remain roughly constant in a neighborhood of the plate as you pull it away, but fall off rapidly as you slide the magnet off of the side of the plate.

Comment: @Jerry: when you pull a magnet off a surface, the force goes down very rapidly, so much of the work is done in the first mm or less.  On the other hand, if you pull a magnet off the edge of a plate, the force decreases gradually the entire width of the magnet. I assume this is what is going on.

Comment: For example, look at [this force-distance](http://www.kjmagnetics.com/largergraph.asp?CI=1&pName=DX0X0) for a 1-in diameter magnet. If you take the integrated area under the curve and spread it out over the inch that it would require to slide it off, the force is clearly going to go down by a lot. I think my answer has to be correct, because otherwise you could get around the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: Peter, please do explain how if you are wrong this goes beyond the laws of thermodynamics and C.O.E?

Comment: @HYP: ignoring friction, the energy gained by putting a magnet on the plate must be equal to the work required to take it off the plate. Otherwise, energy is not conserved, and [the first law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics#First_law) is violated. This is because, ignoring friction, both the process of lowering the magnet to the plate and sliding it off  can be made adiabatic (so no heat is lost doing this). I realize that there are some technical words (work, energy, adiabatic) in this explanation, but I can't explain them in this comment; look them up.

Comment: Interesting, reviewing this.

Comment: Peter, I think there is something we missed, heres why: When a magnet is attracted to the plate, x work has been done. But when an external force is applied to the magnet to slide it, the only force acting against it is friction. The magnetic force is doing nothing against the work to slide it.

Comment: However, energy is still conserved, when sliding the magnet heat is generated.

Comment: We can't say the work is equal, because the work initially done to attract the magnet is the magnetic force, when sliding the magnet, the magnetic force is applied but the distance( or x) is = 0.

Comment: If the work needed to slide a magnet is less, it violates nothing.

Comment: Think of it with this analogy: When a book is on top of  a table gravity acts on it(f = mg) but does now work since h = 0, by sliding the book the only force acts is  friction. I've even calculated an example, and having the same distance(X) the work is not the same! The work by the magnetic force is greater than the work done by sliding the magnet... Review this concept and think about work. It takes less effort, less energy to slide off a magnet than to pull it. It violates nothing too.. .

Comment: The energy conserved its dissipated into other forms, so when a magnet is stuck to a plate... There is no energy at all. We must put energy back into the system. And we need to see what forces would determine the rate of that energy, you can apply a lot of work by pull the magnet directly off a plate because of the strong magnetic force acting against you, and you can apply less energy to slide it.

Comment: You can consume 100J sliding a rock, and you could consume 10J sliding the same rock on-top of wheels... Try to relate that analogy to it :)

Comment: @HYP: there's a difference between sliding a magnet while it's still on the plate, and sliding it past the edge of the plate and removing it from the plate. In the first case, you're only working against friction. In the second case, you're also working against the magnetic field.

Comment: @PeterShor The magnetic force only acts perpendicularly to the motion, it will not have much of an effect in the second case. If I was wrong it would be semi-impossible to get to magnets separated from each other unless you'd have a SUPER motor to do so. Like this [monster](http://www.kjmagnetics.com/proddetail.asp?prod=BZX0ZX0Y0-N52).

Comment: Please continue this discussion in [chat] (there will be a link that automatically moves it to chat that appears for you). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After much studying, and experimentation.
I conclude that indeed, the force required to "slide" the magnet's is less than the force required to "pull" them directly off.